# mysql with few tables, subquery on one large table performs slow

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, query-performance

We are experiencing slow performance with a query on mysql database and we are not sure if the query is wrong or maybe mysql or server is not good enough.

The query with a subquery returns some project details (3 fields) and filename of the latest taken picture of a online camera.

Info
Table 'projects' contains 40 records.
Table 'cameras' contains approx 40 records (1 project, multiple cameras possible)
Table 'cameraimages' contains around 250000 (250 thousand) records. (1 camera can have thousands of images)
Engine is InnoDb
Database size is about 100Mb approx
No indexes are added yet.

Version number mysql 8.0.15

This is the query

```
SELECT
    pj.title,
    pj.description,
    pj.city,
    (SELECT cmi.filename 
       FROM cameras cm
       LEFT JOIN cameraimages cmi ON cmi.cameraId = cm.id
      WHERE cm.projectId = pj.id
      ORDER BY cmi.dateRecording DESC 
      LIMIT 0,1) as latestfilename
FROM
    projects pj
```

It takes 40-50 seconds to return this data.
That is to long for a webpage but I think it should take not that long at all.
We tested the same query on another server, to compare. Same data, same query.
That takes 25 seconds.

My questions are:

1. Is this query to 'heavy/bad' and if it is, what query should perform better?
2. Is there a way, or what should I check, to find out why this query runs better on an older/other server?

Hope someone can give some advice.
Thnx!

Additional info

```
CREATE TABLE `cameras` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cameraUid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cameraFriendlyName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `projectId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateModified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createArchive` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `createDaily` smallint(6) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=88 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Columns cameraId,dateRecording is unique.
One camera takes on picture at the time.

Comment: Please add the version of your MySql in question.

Comment: can you include `show create table cameras` in your question?

Comment: is `(cameraId, dateRecording)` unique?

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-performance/info and [edit] your question to give more information.

Comment: Can you publish the explain only of a single subquery using any project id?

EXPLAIN SELECT cmi.filename ....

ALSO, you should try to replace the LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN since LEFT JOIN can prevent some optimization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a so-called *dependent subquery*. That's slow.

I guess `cameraimages.id` is a primary key for your cameraimages file. That's a guess. You didn't provide enough information in your question to answer it with certainty.

I also guess that the `dateRecording` values in `cameraimages` are in the same order as your autoincrementing primary key `id` values.  That is, I guess you INSERT a record to that table at the time each image is captured.

Let's break this down.

You want the `id` of the most recent image from each project. How can you get that? Write a subquery to retrieve the largest, most recent `id` for each project.

```
                         SELECT cm.projectId,
                                MAX(cmi.id) imageId
                           FROM cameras cm
                           JOIN cameraimages cmi ON cmi.cameraId = cm.id
                          GROUP BY cm.projectId
```

That subquery does the heavy lifting of searching your big table.  It does it just once, not for every project, so it won't take as long.

Then put that subquery into your query to retrieve the columns you need.

```
 SELECT 
       pj.title,
       pj.description,
       pj.city,
       cmi.filename latestfilename
  FROM projects pj
  JOIN (
                         SELECT cm.projectId,
                                MAX(cmi.id) imageId
                           FROM cameras cm
                           JOIN cameraimages cmi ON cmi.cameraId = cm.id
                          GROUP BY cm.projectId
       ) latest ON pj.id = latest.projectId
  JOIN cameraimages cmi ON cmi.imageId = latest.imageId
```

This has a series of JOINs making a chain from `projects` to the `latest` subquery and from there to `cameraimages`.

This depends on `cameraimages.id` values being in chronological order. It can still be done if they aren't in that order with a more elaborate query.

Comment: Thank you! This query runs already faster, less than 2 seconds. Great. The only thing is that max(cmi.id) does not have to be the latest image, as you already mentioned. most of the time it is but dateRecording contains the datetime value which is more important than the id. So, if we decide or need to import extra images from yesterday, the (max) id would return an image from yesterday. I do not see how I should change your query to make that happen. I can get the max(dateRecording) but that does not return the filename value?

Comment: RIght.  It's harder without chronological `id` values. Working on it now.

Answer (score 0):

When `cameraimages.id` values aren't in chronological order, we need to work with the latest `dateRecording` values.

This is going to require a sequence of subqueries. So, rather than nesting them, let's use MySQL 8+ Common Table Expressions.  It's a big query.

```
WITH 
ProjectCameraImage AS (
     /* a virtual version of the cameraimages table including projectId */
     SELECT cmi.id, cmi.dateRecording, cm.projectId, cm.cameraId 
       FROM cameras cm
       JOIN cameraimages cmi ON cm.id = cmi.cameraId
),
```

```
LatestDate AS (
     /* the latest date for each entry in ProjectCameraImage */
     /* Notice how this uses MAX rather than ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1 */
     SELECT projectId, cameraId, 
            MAX(dateRecording) dateRecording
       FROM ProjectCameraImage
      GROUP BY projectId, cameraId
),
```

```
ProjectCameraLatest AS (
      /* the cameraimage.id values for the latest images in ProjectCameraImage */
      SELECT ProjectCameraImage.id, 
             ProjectCameraImage.projectId, 
             ProjectCameraImage.cameraId,
             ProjectCameraImage.dateRecording
        FROM ProjectCameraImage 
        JOIN LatestDate
                 ON ProjectCameraImage.projectId = LatestDate.projectId
                AND ProjectCameraImage.cameraId = LatestDate.cameraId
                AND ProjectCameraImage.dateRecording = LatestDate.dateRecording
),
```

```
LatestProjectDate AS (
       /* the latest data for each entry in ProjectCameraLatest */
       SELECT projectId, 
              MAX(dateRecording) dateRecording
         FROM ProjectCameraLatest
        GROUP BY projectId
),
```

```
ProjectLatest AS (
        /* the cameraimage.id values for the latest images in ProjectCameraLatest */
        SELECT ProjectCameraLatest.id,
               ProjectCameraLatest.projectId
          FROM ProjectCameraLatest
          JOIN LatestProjectDate 
                ON ProjectCameraLatest.projectId = LatestProjectDate.projectId
               AND ProjectCameraLatest.dateRecording = LatestProjectDate.dateRecording
)
```

```
/* the main query */
SELECT pj.title,
       pj.description,
       pj.city,
       cmi.filename latestfilename
  FROM projects pj
  JOIN ProjectLatest ON pj.id = ProjectLatest.projectId
  JOIN cameraimages cmi ON ProjectLatest.id = cmi.id;
```

It's big because we have to go through two different cycles of finding the `cameraimages.id` value with the largest `dateRecording`.

**Edit** The heavy lifting, in terms of searching your tables, happens in the second common table expression (CTE), the one called `LatestDate`.  I suggest adding an index to your `cameraimages` table as follows to give it a boost.

```
CREATE INDEX cmi_cameraid_daterec 
          ON cameraimages (cameraId, dateRecording DESC);
```

That compound index should allow random access by `cameraId`, then quick access to the latest  date. Notice that it also should help the ProjectCameraLatest CTE.

You can test the performance of this by changing the last `SELECT`, the one in the main query, to just `SELECT * FROM LatestDate;`. And to see whether / how it uses the index try [using EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html): use `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM LatestDate;` as the main query.

You may learn some useful things about indexes if you run EXPLAIN with and without the index.

Comment: Wow. Beautiful way of selecting! I had to add 'ProjectCameraImage.dateRecording' column to the 'ProjectCameraLatest' table to make it work but than it works well. It takes 10 seconds instead of 2 to return the data. So, although I like (and learned) from this approach and it does return exactly what we want, it is not a faster way. I am thinking about something like selecting the dateRecording column value as a string, unixtimestamp, which gives us the possibility to get the max(dateRecordingConverted) ? Can be time consuming as well..don't know? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Don't convert dates to text strings, even numeric ones, before doing MAX or other aggregates. DMBS software is almost magically efficient at date arithmetic, and you probably can't outsmart it.  Have you added any indexes to your tables yet? That's your next optimization step.

Comment: Ok, clear. 
There are no index yet. I have added one last week on cameraId but that slowed things down. Are the ones mentioned in the post of Rick James ok? 
Would it be a idea to add an extra column to store the dateRecording as unixtimestamp or string and then select with MAX?

Comment: Please see my edit to my answer. @RickJames's second index is OK, but the way I cast the query here it doesn't need the `filename` column. His third index is redundant to his second index (all indexes include the table's PK). His first index is fine, but your `cameras` table is tiny.  Epic question!  Read https://use-the-index-luke.com/ to learn about indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes:

```
cm:   INDEX(projectId, id)
cmi:  INDEX(cameraId, dateRecording, filename)
cmi:  INDEX(cameraId, id)
```

Comment: Thnx. The suggested query by o.Jonees in the ealier post already has great advantage. Do these indexes still add more benefits?

Comment: @Midiman7472 - possibly.  One of them is tailored specifically to his recommended query formulation.